# Angular 16 standalone app - trying to use signals - value not updating

Tags: angular

I have a standalone app, I'm creating the starting logic of my app on main.ts and there at the end I have my bootstrapping.

here, I make the key network call, it takes up to 6 seconds to retrieve the info so the sooner the better.

```
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { signal } from '@angular/core';
import { StoreService } from 'src/app/services/ctstore/ctstore.service';

export const initialLoadOngoing = signal('initial');

async function initializeApp(): Promise<void> {
    const backend: HttpBackend = new HttpXhrBackend({ build: () => new XMLHttpRequest() });
    const httpClient = provideHttpClientWithInterceptor(backend);
    const storeService = new StoreService();

    const availRequestService = new AvailRequestService(httpClient, storeService);
    availRequestService.getCarList().subscribe((data) => {
        storeService.setCarAvailResults(data);
        console.log(storeService.getStore());
        initialLoadOngoing.set('done');
    });

    // Bootstrap Angular application
    bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
        providers: [
            { provide: HttpClient, useValue: httpClient }
        ]
    }).catch((err) => console.error(err));
}

initializeApp();
```

and my appComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit, effect } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { initialLoadOngoing } from 'src/main';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [CommonModule],
    template: `<div>{{ isLoading }}</div>`,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    isLoading = 'default';

    constructor() {
        effect(() => {
            this.isLoading = initialLoadOngoing();
        });
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        // Other initialization code
    }
}
```

When I load the app, on the browser I see

initial

which means the signal is being passed.

The issue is that when the subscription is resolved, I don't get the updated value.
I do get the console.log inside the subscription to run, so it's resolving properly.
Also no errors in the logs, just the set not updating.

If I add a setInterval in the appcomponent.ts and set a new value, it does update. It's just the `initialLoadOngoing.set('done');` "not working"

Comment: Should probably pass it as a signal

isLoading = signal('default')

constructor() { 
  this.isLoading.set('not-default')
}

Comment: @SimonDragsbæk but I need the info to pass from main.ts to appComponent, asigning it value in the appComponent is irrelevant, I'm just "proving that the signal is imported correctly as it works, the issue is that it doesnt trigger an update on main.ts when the subscription is done

Comment: effect would be called during change detection on the component if the dependency value changes. i.e. it doesnt just trigger if ignal updates

Comment: hey @Andrei so, how do I get to trigger it?

Comment: you can restructure your code so your http query would be run in angular zone. this way change detection would be triggered. signals are pull+push - they don't just "notify" subscribers about updates - it is not possible (yet) to force change detection with just signals apis

Comment: ah I see. @Andrei maybe what i can do is create a behaviorSubject, and convert it to signal? maybe after the first event? i'd love to use signals, they're super clean. I can't move the logic inside angular because with my current approach I can preload my "widget" in a previous page, cache this long http request, and the sencond time it loads the component with the logic to bootstrap the app all the info will be there

Comment: even if you convert your subject to signal effect won't be triggered. what you can try is take the result of `const ref = bootstrapApplication(...` - it will return AppRef.  and at the moment you want CD to tgigger - call `ref.tick()`. I think this way your example would work

Answer (score 1):

Change you AppComponent to something like the following:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, effect } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { initialLoadOngoing } from 'src/main';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [CommonModule],
    template: `<div>{{ isLoading() }}</div><!-- Notice the parentheses -->`,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    /** Set the reference to the signal and call it in the template */
    isLoading = initialLoadOngoing;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        // Other initialization code
    }
}
```

Basically, the view in your code is not updating because the change detection is not triggered (since you are outside the change detection by calling the signal in the effect).

As per the docs, you should not use effects to introduce side-effects and are meant for things like logging.

Answer (score 0):

So, Signals don't trigger view refreshes.

Still haven't found a workaround, they talk about using

```
    import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, NgZone, OnInit, effect } from '@angular/core';


    effect(() => {
        this.zone.run(() => {
            this.isLoading = initialLoadOngoing();
            this.cdr.detectChanges();
        });
    });
```

But that's also not working for me. might need to go back to good ol' behaviorSubjects

[Angular 16 Signal update doesn't update view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76445729/angular-16-signal-update-doesnt-update-view)